# How to prevent upward rigidbody velocity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, velocity, rigid-bodies

I have a group of objects that I allow my player to toss around the scene in zero gravity. However I want to create type of invisible bounds after a certain height. So far when the object reaches a certain upward bounds, I have been doing this in my FixedUpdate...

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity - Vector3.Project(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity, transform.up);
```

...which works in a sense, but because it is using transform.up, it is removing velocity from both upwards and downwards movement, and I need to restrict it to just upwards movement. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check the y component of the velocity and if it's positive (upwards) set it to 0? If it's negative (downwards) just keep it.

PS. I think you should get a variable referencing the rigidbody component to minimize the GetComponent calls.

```
Vector3 v = rb.velocity; //get the velocity
v.y = v.y > 0 ? 0 : v.y; //set to 0 if positive
rb.velocity = v; //apply the velocity
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if position hits the threshold and if object is currently moving upwards

```c#
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
[SerializeField] private float maxY;

private void Awake()
{
    if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var velocity = rb.velocity; 
    if(rb.position.y >= maxY && velocity.y > 0) 
    { 
        velocity.y = 0; 
        rb.velocity = velocity; 
    }
}
```